# Статус 404 при отправке PUT-запроса Spring MVC и REST Assured

Tags: java, spring-mvc, rest

Зак выглядит контроллер:

```html
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('CONFIGURATION_SET_BASE_URL')")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/baseUrl/{tBaseUrl:.*}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public ResponseEntity setBaseUrl(@PathVariable String tBaseUrl)
            throws IOException,
                   AuthenticationException,
                   JAXBException
{}
```

Вот тест:

```html
String baseUrl = "http://localhost:" + 40080 + "/newurl";

        String url = getContextBaseUrl() + "/configuration/strongbox/baseUrl/" + baseUrl;

        RestAssuredMockMvc.given()
                          .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
                          .body(baseUrl)
                          .when()
                          .put(url)
                          .peek() // Use peek() to print the ouput
                          .then()
                          .statusCode(200)
                          .extract();
```

Тест не проходит. Возвращает статус 404
Вот стектрейс:

```html
java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
Expected status code <200> doesn't match actual status code <404>.


 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:80)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.doConstructorInvoke(CachedConstructor.java:74)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrap.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:84)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:60)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:235)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:247)
 at com.jayway.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl$HamcrestAssertionClosure.validate(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:584)
 at com.jayway.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl$HamcrestAssertionClosure$validate.call(Unknown Source)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
 at com.jayway.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl.validateResponseIfRequired(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:738)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:59)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:166)
 at com.jayway.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl.statusCode(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:107)
 at com.jayway.restassured.specification.ResponseSpecification$statusCode$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:166)
 at com.jayway.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl.statusCode(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:115)
 at com.jayway.restassured.internal.ValidatableResponseOptionsImpl.statusCode(ValidatableResponseOptionsImpl.java:115)
 at org.carlspring.strongbox.rest.ConfigurationManagementControllerTest.testSetAndGetBaseUrl(ConfigurationManagementControllerTest.java:128)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
 at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
 at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
 at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
 at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
 at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:254)
 at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
 at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
 at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
 at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
 at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
 at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
 at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
 at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:253)
 at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Comment: Добавьте простой маршрут типа `@RequestMapping(value = "/foo}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)` и потестируйте. Затем добавьте `@RequestMapping(value = "/foo/{bar}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)` и задайте `@PathVariable String bar` в параметрах метода. Потестируйте. А потом посмотрите, что будет если Вы объявите в параметрах `@PathVariable String tBaseUrl:.*` в своём методе вместо `@PathVariable String tBaseUrl`.

Comment: В последнем случае, скорее всего, будут жалобы. Я думаю, Вам нужно вытащить квантификаторы за фигурные скобки в `value = "/baseUrl/{tBaseUrl:.*}"` - вот так: `value = "/baseUrl/{tBaseUrl}:.*"`.

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, Вам нужно вытащить квантификаторы за фигурные скобки в `value = "/baseUrl/{tBaseUrl:.*}"` - вот так: `value = "/baseUrl/{tBaseUrl}:.*"`

Для отлова порта, по которому было обращение к маршруту, воспользуйтесь `@Value("${local.ser‌​ver.port}")`.

Но прежде Вам нужно разрешить обращение к серверу по любому порту через назначение `server.port=0` в `/src/main/resources/‌​application.properti‌​es`.
(Подробнее [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21083170/spring-boot-how-to-configure-port))
(Альтернатива: `Run Configuration -> VM Option -Dserver.port=0`)

Разрешили обращение по любому порту. Ок. Теперь, пожалуйста, определите поле в вашем классе `@Value("${local.ser‌​‌​ver.port}") private String myPort;` пропишите такой маршрут в аннотации: `@RequestMapping(val‌​ue = "/foo", method = RequestMethod.PUT)` и в теле метода для маршрута пропишите вывод `myPort`. Далее, обратитесь к своему серверу по адресу `http://localhost:40‌​080/foo`. Посмотрите, какой будет вывод.

Comment: Нет, не помогло. Даже разные комбинации делал типа: 
{tBaseUrl}:.*
{tBaseUrl:}.*
и т.д.
Да и тут указано, что я делаю синтаксически верно http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates
Вот только почему не работает

Comment: а если убрать двоеточие из шаблона? Просто порт отлавливается отдельно, вроде как. И сделать так: `value = "/baseUrl/{tBaseUrl}.*"`

Comment: Все равно. Да и оно должно там быть. нет, все идет одной строкой. Так и делал. По-другому - синтаксическая ошибка.

Comment: Вы порт ловите. Тогда тут дело не в пути, а в порту, на котором развёрнут сервер. Посмотрите, какие порты слушает Ваш сервер приложений. Возможно, Вам сначала нужно задать диапазон портов в настройках сервера, на которых Вы желаете слушать обращения клиентов. А дальше - посмотреть, как организовать работу по портам.

Comment: Порт ловится строкой. А потом сервис с ним работает. Он никакого отношения к ПУТ запросу не имеет. Смотрите, как выглядит полный адрес: http://localhost:48080/configuration/strongbox/baseUrl/http://localhost:40080/newurl

Comment: Вот здесь Ваша задача озвучена и даны некоторые рекомендации: http://www.cyberforum.ru/java-j2ee/thread1784359.html. Цитата: "HTTPS должен быть сконфигурирован в секьюрити конфиге спринга. Там можно настраивать на каждый адрес протокол." Но это удобно для некоторого конечного известного множества портов.

Comment: Да, именно о чём я и говорю. `:48080` - это порт. Вот, похоже, решение: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21083170/spring-boot-how-to-configure-port

Comment: В /src/main/resources/, в application.properties прописываем `server.port=0` для доступа по любому порту. И для получения информации о порте можно использовать `@Value("${local.server.port}")`.

Comment: Прописал в Run Configuration -> VM Option
-Dserver.port=0
и не помогло

Comment: Дело в том, что остальные тесты работают. Не работает именно этот. И есть в этом в пути не передавать всякие двоеточия и слешы, то все хорошо. Т.е. я предполагаю, что дело в маске пути

Comment: Разрешили обращение по любому порту. Ок. Теперь, пожалуйста, определите поле в вашем классе `@Value("${local.ser‌​ver.port}")
    private String myPort;` пропишите такой маршрут в аннотации: `@RequestMapping(value = "/foo", method = RequestMethod.PUT)`
и в теле метода для маршрута пропишите вывод `myPort`. Далее, обратитесь к своему серверу по адресу `http://localhost:40080/foo`. Посмотрите, какой будет вывод.

Comment: Дело даже не в маске пути, а в том, к каким данным и как мы обращаемся.

Comment: nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'local.ser‌​‌​ver.port' in string value "${local.ser‌​‌​ver.port}"

Comment: Spring Boot в зависимостях? (плюс здесь был поднят вопрос https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1798)

Comment: Какие именно зависимости нужно добавить? Там их много

Comment: Из документации: "`@Value("${local.server.port}")`. Don’t try to inject the port in a regular application.". (Документация: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html). Вот ещё пост на тему: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30312058/spring-boot-how-to-get-the-running-port

Answer (score 0):

А какой ответ будет, если такой адрес в браузере открыть? Подозреваю, что дело в том, что вы указали тип содержимого как `text/plain`, но контроллер ожидает `text/html`. Попробуйте добавить аттрибут `consumes` к `@RequestMapping`, например.

Comment: Добавил consumes = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE и не помогло